# How to split comma-separated values?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to split a comma-separated string in `Category` column :

| Category |
| --- |
| Auto,A,1234444 |
| Auto,B,2345444 |
| Electronincs,Computer,33443434 |

I want to get only a single value from above string:

```
value1: Auto
value2: A
value3: 1234444
```

I found how using `Replace()` and `Trim()`. However, I want an easier approach. In SQL there is `SubString()` but not in SQLite. `substr()` can set a maximum length but my string doesn't have fixed length.

Comment: @dipali is it possible to get the whole `String` first, then process it in Java? (using `String.split(",")`)

Comment: @AndrewT. its not possible.my query is not enough for this.i have already create 10 line query and i just put this question solution there..please help me.

Comment: if you only have to split into two columns https://www.pauldesalvo.com/split-a-column-with-a-delimiter-in-sqlite/ shows a viable answer for three columns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443919/split-one-column-into-three-columns-based-on-a-delimiter

Answer (score 47):

You can use a [Common Table Expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) to split comma separated values in SQLite.

```
WITH split(word, csv) AS (
  -- 'initial query' (see SQLite docs linked above)
  SELECT 
    -- in final WHERE, we filter raw csv (1st row) and terminal ',' (last row)
    '', 
    -- here you can SELECT FROM e.g. another table: col_name||',' FROM X
    'Auto,A,1234444'||',' -- terminate with ',' indicating csv ending
  -- 'recursive query'
  UNION ALL SELECT
    substr(csv, 0, instr(csv, ',')), -- each word contains text up to next ','
    substr(csv, instr(csv, ',') + 1) -- next recursion parses csv after this ','
  FROM split -- recurse
  WHERE csv != '' -- break recursion once no more csv words exist
) SELECT word FROM split 
WHERE word!=''; -- filter out 1st/last rows
```

Output is as expected:

```
Auto
A
1234444
```

Comment: how can this query be modified to work on a simple table like `CREATE TABLE tablename (id INT,name VARCHAR(20));` where name has comma separated values?

Comment: @indago: Create a view that selects id and the split name? Is this what you mean?

Comment: It has problem when only one item in the string, for example `trim('Auto', ',')`, there is no output.

Comment: We can modify the `substr` part into `substr(str, 0, case when instr(str, ',') then instr(str, ',') else length(str)+1 end)`, in order to print the string without comma delimiter.

Comment: How to use it on a column after a select?

Comment: This might be clearer if you added the keyword `recursive` to show how it's splitting each row of `split` till it can't split any more.

Comment: Great example! The final SELECT slightly confused me by making me wonder how an empty string got inserted in the 'word' column. Finally, I concluded it didn't, and the final SELECT could have just been `SELECT word FROM split`.

Comment: "split" keyword may not work with the pre-lollipop android OS sqlite version. As I checked with the samsung galaxy s3 device running on android OS 4.3, was throwing error and unable to execute query that contains "split" keyword.

Comment: In addition to above comment, error is thrown in android os 4.3 `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "split":`

Comment: @DhavalShah use the custom [SQLite android bindings](https://sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) which will have the latest SQLite features.

Comment: the answer shows how to handle a row not a table.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl see my edit, showing an example handling a table in comments (`col_name||',' FROM X` instead of `'Auto,A,1234444'||','`). The latter (single hard-coded row) just makes it easy to paste into any SQLite client to get an instantly working example

Comment: Don't comment on the answer. they are really hard to read.

Comment: in your answer, where is table name???

Answer (score 8):

SQLite provide functions for this purpose, e.g. to get substring `substr('your string', start_position, end_position)`, to get position of a specific character in a string `instr('22:string', ':')`, and to get length of a string `length('string')`.
Now let see the following examples:

```
select substr('22:khan', x, y);
returns a string starting at x and ends with y;
select substr('22:khan', 0, instr('22:khan',':'));
returns: 22 
select substr('22:khan', instr('22:khan',':')+1, length('22:khan'));
returns: khan
select substr('22:khan',instr('22:khan',':'), length('22:khan'));
returns: :khan
select substr('Noor,Khan', 0, instr('Noor,Khan', ','));
returns: Noor
select substr('Noor,Khan', instr('Noor,Khan', ',')+1, length('Noor,Khan'));
returns: Khan
```

for more info visit: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Comment: unfortunately, `instr` only finds the first instance of the separateor character.  suppose you had the strings "asdfa:bfab:zarva"... how would you find the third colon delimited word?

Comment: @Michael use the position of the first match + 1 as the starting position of the next substring, and repeat

Answer (score 5):

I like the answer from @user1461607 except: it seems to me the SQLite documentation warns against assuming any particular order from a SELECT, both in the general case, and in the specific case of a recursive SELECT. Here, I modified that answer to add an ordering column in a manner that I *think* SQLite guarantees to work.

I also cosmetically changed the example from a comma-separated list to a path, to suggest there are cases where you really need to process things in a particular order. This example also prints out all the columns from the temporary table so it's slightly easier to see what went on. AFAICT, a CTE in SQLite does not have the usual ROWID column, so it seems like adding some ordering column yourself really is required to sleep soundly at night.

```
WITH RECURSIVE split(seq, word, str) AS (
    SELECT 0, '/', 'home/ronburk/layers/branch'||'/'
    UNION ALL SELECT
        seq+1,
        substr(str, 0, instr(str, '/')),
        substr(str, instr(str, '/')+1)
    FROM split WHERE str != ''
) SELECT * FROM split ORDER BY split.seq ASC;
```

Comment: "split" keyword may not work with the pre-lollipop android OS sqlite version. As I checked with the samsung galaxy s3 device running on android OS 4.3, was throwing error and unable to execute query that contains "split" keyword. Error: `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "split"`

Answer (score 2):

This variation of the answer provided by @user1461607
ensures that any CSV values that happen to be empty strings are preserved:

```
WITH RECURSIVE split(value, str) AS (
      SELECT null, 'Auto,A,1234444' || ','  -- the string to be split 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
      substr(str, 0, instr(str, ',')),
      substr(str, instr(str, ',')+1)
      FROM split WHERE str!=''
  ) SELECT value FROM split WHERE value is not NULL;
```

#### Converting a CSV line to a JSON array

Assuming the JSON1 extension has been loaded, you could use `json_group_array(value)` in the last line to convert
the CSV to a JSON array of strings.

Comment: "split" keyword may not work with the pre-lollipop android OS sqlite version. As I checked with the samsung galaxy s3 device running on android OS 4.3, was throwing error and unable to execute query that contains "split" keyword. Error: `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "split"`

Comment: I just had to some small changes to better suit my needs, but this is working perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I found an extension which replicates the behaviour of the SPLIT_PART function of PostgreSQL

```
SELECT split_part(category, ',', 3) FROM ...
```

https://github.com/nalgeon/sqlean/blob/main/docs/text.md#split_partsource-sep-part

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.