# Split one column into three columns based on a delimiter "|"

Tags: sql, substring

I have a table

```
id  methods
1   a|b|c
2   e|f|g
```

how can I change the table to

```
id method1 method2 method3
1    a       b       c
2    e       f       g
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: The answer to this _might_ depend upon which RDBMS you are using. Or do you want a "pure" ANSI SQL answer?

Comment: Fix your schema, if you can. Storing delimited data in a column is almost never a good idea, and you're finding out one reason why.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which RDBMS you are using but I got this to work in Sql Server, MySql and SQLite. This makes the assumption that there are only three items that need to be split out of the string

To reiterate what @Joel Coehoorn mentioned. This can be very slow when given a lot of data. It is best to change the schema of the table and have the data split before it is ever inserted in the table

**SQL Server Version**

```
select  t.id, t.methods,
 SUBSTRING(t.methods, 1, CHARINDEX('|', t.methods)-1) as method1,
 SUBSTRING(t.methods, CHARINDEX('|', t.methods)+1, CHARINDEX('|', t.methods, CHARINDEX('|', t.methods)+1)-CHARINDEX('|', t.methods)-1) as method2,
 SUBSTRING(t.methods, CHARINDEX('|', t.methods, CHARINDEX('|', t.methods)+1)+1,len(t.methods)) as method3
 from TestTable t
```

**MySql Version**

```
select  t.id, t.methods,
 SUBSTRING(t.methods, 1, LOCATE('|', t.methods)-1) as method1,
 SUBSTRING(t.methods, LOCATE('|', t.methods)+1, LOCATE('|', t.methods, LOCATE('|', t.methods)+1)-LOCATE('|', t.methods)-1) as method2,
 SUBSTRING(t.methods, LOCATE('|', t.methods, LOCATE('|', t.methods)+1)+1) as method3
 from TestTable t
```

**SQLite**

```
 select 
 SUBSTR(t.methods, 1, INSTR(t.methods, '|')-1) as method1,
 SUBSTR(t.methods, INSTR(t.methods, '|')+1, INSTR(SUBSTR(t.methods, INSTR(t.methods, '|')+1), '|')-1) as method2,
 SUBSTR(t.methods, INSTR(SUBSTR(t.methods, INSTR(t.methods, '|')+1), '|')+ INSTR(t.methods, '|')+1) as method3
 from TestTable t
```