# Find the most common word in a sql column (with multiple words)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

For example, I have this column in sqlite3:

```
hello world
hello you two
hello world
hello hello
```

I want to extract the most popular word and its occurences.
However, untill now, it seems its only possible to find the occurences of a cell. Like this:

```
SELECT titles, COUNT(titles) 
FROM standart_results
GROUP BY titles
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

It will return `("hello world", 2)`.
But I want `("hello", 5)`.

I can not use `LIKE` as well since I do not know what word has the most occurences.

Do I need to transfer the data into a variable and use regex on it or can I do it with sql?

Comment: Can you use the `split()` tag?

Comment: yes but for that I would have to transfer all the data into a python variable which would slow me down. If possible, I would select all the data from sqlite directly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split comma-separated value in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258878/how-to-split-comma-separated-value-in-sqlite)

Comment: Just replace , with space and the above answer will help

Comment: Ok thanks I will try it later

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=50aabb9fccb7192b6cbb8aa765d12810, just add `LIMIT 1` to only get the top result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have really good string processing capabilities and no method for returning a table.  However, it does support recursive CTEs.  And you can use this construct to break the title into words:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select null as word, title || ' ' as rest, 0 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select substr(rest, 1, instr(rest, ' ') - 1) as word, 
             substr(rest, instr(rest, ' ') + 1) rest,
             lev + 1
      from cte
      where lev < 5 and rest like '% %'
     )
select word, count(*)
from cte
where word is not null
group by word;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fa4fa8591c7918a0a26c56fe00c9a9b0) is a db<>fiddle.

To get the top word, you can use:

```
select word, count(*)
from cte
where word is not null
group by word
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

```
SELECT titles, COUNT(titles) as Appearances
FROM standart_results
GROUP BY titles
ORDER BY Appearances DESC LIMIT 1
```