# Convert split_string to SQLite query

Tags: sql, sqlite, split

I have been trying to convert `split_string` syntax to SQLite from SQL Server. I couldn't find any alternative to do that. can anyone please help me to do that.

```
SELECT row_number () over (order by (select 0)) rn, value
FROM string_split(Nav_Path,''/'')
```

This is the SQL query that needs to write in SQLite. There is syntax error saying

> Transaction ERROR: sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: no such table: string_split

Thank you

Comment: sqlite didn't suppot `string_split` function.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258878/how-to-split-comma-separated-value-in-sqlite) helps ?

Comment: I have tried that but i have no idea where to apply that

Comment: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=106be7ebde6e18b5d4abeaac0e2e2625)*